# Comparing survival times in small samples for two groups

Tags: binomial-distribution, cox-model, permutation-test, kaplan-meier

I am working on a dataset of big cats. 18 cats have a particular antigen and the rest (58) do not. We have contact times for when blood samples were taken - so when the cats were identified as having the particular antigen - ages, and death times for all animals (they are very well monitored so all times are believed to be accurate).

I'm currently trying to determine whether the antigen confers any particular advantage in terms of survival times.

The age distributions of the positive and negative (for antigen) cats are different - thus a straight up comparison of survival time means for example is out of the question.

My first attempt was to do survival analysis using weights to adjust the proportions in each age bin such that the effective number of cats per age category was equal between the positive and negative cats. Kaplan-Meier curves were drawn and coxph (in R) was used to calculate a proportional hazard.

An alternative I wanted to try was to pair match cats by age (positive with negative) and use binomial distributions to see whether there was an improvement in outcomes (who lives longer) based on the null hypothesis that the antigen doesn't do anything (and therefore 50% of the time positive cats should outlive negative cats and vice versa). Because pair-matching cats is random - lots of cats are similar ages - the matching procedure throws up wildly different answers based on which particular cats are paired together.

My two questions based on all this, are:

1. Is the weighted Kaplan-Meier approach at all valid? I think it corresponds to "re-sampling" when I provide weights using this method in R. I've gone around in circles thinking about this and not sure what I think any more.
2. Is there any approach with matching similarly aged cats in pairs that could be consistent and give an overall average hazard - or p-value to say whether the cats have equivalent outcomes based on antigen presence/absence. My issue here is that if I match cats to those within 3 months age of them, then there are lots of choices of partner so it gets very messy. Are permutation tests the right approach for this?

Apologies for the waffle - I've been thinking about this for days and it's all got very mixed up in my head.

Thanks

Comment: Is the antigen presence associated with longer of shorter lifetimes? Is antigen presence associated with a younger or an older population of cats? Were the ages at blood sampling well within the normal lifespan of such cats (i.e., might many members of the underlying population have died before a typical blood-sampling age)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inverse-probability weighted Kaplan-Meier curves, and the associated log-rank test. See Cole and Hernan Computer Methods and Programs in Biomedicine 2004. You may need to bootstrap to get the correct variance estimate.